# Conditions for a Binomial Random Variable

Tags: binomial-distribution

I understand for a random variable to be distributed binomially:

- There must be n fixed trials
- Each trial must be independent of the others
- Probability of success must remain constant throughout the trials
- Outcome either happens or doesn't happen

So take this set up (sorry for the big chunk of text):

A university scholarship committee must select two students to receive a certain scholarship. The committee receives eight applications for the scholarships - five from male students and three from female students. The applicants are all equally qualified, so the two scholarship winners are randomly selected from the eight applicants. Let
X
be the number of female students who receive a scholarship.

From what I understand, X is indeed a binomial random variable but this is where my confusion arises.

Is X ~ Bin(3,3/8) or X ~ (8,3/8)?

I wasn't sure if n refers to all 8 possible students or just the 3 female students.

Comment: The trials are not independent.  Knowing that, say, the first male student was accepted reduces the chances that the first female student was accepted.

Comment: If you like, you can imagine that each student is distinguished, not just by gender (so we have $M_1, \cdots, M_5, F_1, F_2, F_3$.  Then, since any pair is equally likely to be drawn, you are just making a single selection from a set with $\binom 82$ elements.

Comment: @Lulu oh so, say I were to pick a female student for the first scholarship, then that means the probability of picking the female student the next one is going to be 2/7. So the probability isn't fixed and so X isn't binomially distributed?

Comment: You could draw a simple tree diagram to find the probabilities of $0, 1$ or $2$ females

Comment: @DavidQuinn yea I understand how to work out the probabilities, just less so the definition of X as a binomial random variable

Comment: It isn't binomial, because of the dependence between the trials.  It's still easy to count, of course.

Comment: If you know how to work out the probabilities, then you can see the values are not from a Binomial Distribution. I hope it’s clear why it’s not Binomial.

Comment: @DavidQuinn yes I see that the probability isn't constant throughout the trials thanks